# Getting error message in try catch (C#, Window Service)

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get error message in try catch on C# (or window service that was written with C#) like this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
while (input!="q")
{
    try
    {
        double result = 10 / int.Parse(input);
        Console.WriteLine("Divinced by " + input + " And result is " + result);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, Please try again");
    }
    finally
    {
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It was built to ".exe" program.
If I input character ("A","B","C") or zero, then the program will show message "Error, Please try again" so I need to know error message.
I don't want to edit code. I need a tools to detect all error in program.

Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Like `catch (Exception e){ Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }` ?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't want to edit any source code because it is "exe" file.

Answer (score 0):

You want the exception's `Message` property to be printed. Replace your `catch` block with this:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred : " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: "I don't want to edit code" - The user does not want to modify the code. Please read the entire post.

Comment: Actually, I need some tool to show me error message because I have an "exe" program and I can't see any source code. Thank you